# Print out the index and the element

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

So I am writing a program supposed to print out the position in the array and the number at that position (by using linear search). Here is what I've got so far, but the output was not what I expected.

Output:

```
Number 0  Linear Search Index At 0
Number 1  Linear Search Index At 1
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 2
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 2
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 2
Number 3  Linear Search Index At 5
```

My expected Output:

```
Number 0  Linear Search Index At 0
Number 1  Linear Search Index At 1
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 2
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 3
Number 2  Linear Search Index At 4
Number 3  Linear Search Index At 5
```

Code:

```
    public class LinearSearch {
    public int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
        int size = array.length;
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            if ( array[i] == key ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 26, 27, 27, 28, 30};

        LinearSearch linSearch = new LinearSearch();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + array[i] + " " + " Linear Search Index " +
                linSearch.linearSearch(array, array[i]));
        }
    }

  }
```

Any helps would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. You algorithm is looking for **the first** match.

Answer (score 1):

`i` in your `linearSearch()` function always starts from 0 ie. `linearSearch()` always starts its search from the beginning of the array. Therefore, `linearSearch()` will always return the first element which matches your key.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have it will return the *first* index where it finds the value:

```
public int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int size = array.length;
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if ( array[i] == key ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So, if your array is `{1,2,2}` and you look for `2`, you will *always* get the index `1` (for the second item in the array).

Unless the array elements are unique, there's no way to fix this in the general case. When looking for an element of which there is more than one, you have to make *some* decision as to which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve your expected Output you can simply do:

```
for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
   System.out.println("Number " + array[i] + " " + " Linear Search Index " + x);
}
```

Your method has two problems: 
1. It tries to find the first occurence of an int, this is why your output is jumbled from your expectations.
2. It is ABSOLUTELY not O(n). It's O(n^2), which is probably what you don't want to do in the first place, since you asked for linear search.

Comment: Thanks. So any suggestion that how can i fix my method to print out my expected output instead of using the code you show above?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a method which finds the position in the array of the number given to it to. Return that position.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you want to use an array or could you use a Collection instead? There are a few solutions you can use to get your result. The most efficient don't go through an array at all.